# MediaResponse not (auto)playing file on phone

Tags: actions-on-google

I've build an agent that uses dialogflow and fulfillment with the actions-on-google library. In a certain intent, the fulfillment sends back a SimpleResponse, a MediaResponse and some Suggestions.
It works fine in the simulator, the audio file in the MediaResponse plays as expected.

When testing the agent in the Google Assistant app on my iPhone however, the audio file isn't playing. There isn't a play/pause button but shows a loading/buffering gif instead. When I click on the loading gif the audio file starts playing and the start/pause button appears.

I don't think this is expected behaviour, is this a bug on Google's end or am I missing something here? Is there even a way to default autoplay the audiofile without the user having to push the icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, this is a bug in Actions on Google and they are working on it.

Answer (score 0):

Media responses are supported out of the box only on Android and Google home devices. You must check for the surface capabilities before trying to play the audio. You can check https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#media_responses for more options and suggestions.

What I would suggest is if you are playing small audio clips in between text/speech data, then use SSML. Check audio tag in the link https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The MediaResponse -as far as I know- works and is supported for the Google Assistant app on iPhone. The MediaResponse appears to work fine, except for not autoplaying audio AND the buffering gif not changing into a 'play' button. The buffering gif acts as a play button though; the audio file starts playing when pressed.
Unfortunately for this project I have to use the MediaResponse as well as SSML, so I can't get out of using this.